# How do I update a file's modification time?

Tags: file, rust, io

I'm trying to update the file modification metadata of a file. I can *access* the [`Metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html#method.modified):

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let metadata = fs::metadata("foo.txt")?;

    if let Ok(time) = metadata.modified() {
        println!("{:?}", time);
    } else {
        println!("Not supported on this platform");
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I don't know how to alter that value though. My instinct was to open existing files in append mode and write an empty string — didn't work.

What would a general approach for this look like?

Comment: Did something like `OpenOptions::new().create(true).write(true).open(path)` not update the modified time? I thought just opening the file in a write mode would do so.

Comment: That was my initial approach after not finding write options in the `Metadata` struct. It does not affect it in any way that I can tell. I even opened and appended an `""` to the end and it doesn't seem to affect it.

Answer (score 5):

The [`set_file_mtime`](https://docs.rs/filetime/latest/filetime/fn.set_file_mtime.html) function from the [`filetime`](https://docs.rs/filetime/latest/filetime/) crate can update the file modification time metadata:

```rust
use filetime::{set_file_mtime, FileTime};

fn main() {
    set_file_mtime("foo.txt", FileTime::now()).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a external crate: `filetime`

Answer (score 2):

No more need of external crate, there is a new API since Rust 1.75.0:

- [`std::fs::File::set_modified`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.set_modified)
- [`std::fs::File::set_times`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.set_times)
- [`std::fs::FileTimes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.FileTimes.html)